# Get only second last record - mysql-query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table record like below:-

**my_table**

```
        id |      rating | description

         1 |         0.0 | bed
         2 |         1.0 | good
         3 |         0.0 | bed
         4 |         1.0 | good
         5 |         0.0 | bed
         6 |         0.0 | bed
         7 |         0.0 | bed
```

Now I shorted this table by rating and I got following result.
(Query : SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY rating DESC)

**Result table**

```
        id | rating      | description

         2 |         1.0 | good
         4 |         1.0 | good
         1 |         0.0 | bed
     ==> 3 |         0.0 | bed
         5 |         0.0 | bed
         6 |         0.0 | bed
         7 |         0.0 | bed
```

Now I want previous record of id = 3.

**expected result**

```
        id | rating      | description

         1 |         0.0 | bed
```

How can I achieve it. within single mysql query?
Please help me.

Comment: What do you really want? (Why you want the previous record of record 3?) Do you want the first record with a rating of 0.0? What does "first" mean? (I assume you mean the first record is the record with a lowest ´id´ but you don't order by id at all.) You could try something as simple as `select * from my_table where rating = {what you want} order by id limit 1`.

Comment: Here id = 3 is not static.Suppose I supplied id = 1 in query then it will retrieve record 4|1.0|good. please reefer question

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 2,1
```

Comment: This is not sensible solution. What happen if I want to retrieve previous record of id 1? Your query will give static output each time

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT prev.id, rating, description
FROM my_table current
JOIN my_table prev
  ON (prev.rating < current.rating) 
     OR (prev.rating = current.rating 
        AND (prev.description < current.description 
            OR (prev.description = current.description AND prev.id < current.id)))
WHERE current.id = @currentId
ORDER BY prev.rating desc, prev.description desc, prev.id desc
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a quick solution:

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE rating='0.0' and id<'3' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

This will select the row with the next lowest ID than the one specified that has a rating of 0.0.  This will work without sorting BUT will not retrieve any rows that have a rating of 1.0, even if they would be the next line.

Comment: Hello 
Robert Seddon-Smith,
This will not working for id = 1.

Comment: Of course not - id1 is the first in your list so there will be no others before it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * from my_table 
where rating<(select max(rating) from my_table)
and
id<3
limit 1;
```