# Display second last record in TextBox (show user when he last Login)

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2003

When ever user Sign In into access (achieved through SQL in VBA) following info is captured in `LoginAuditTbl`

- `LoginAuditID` - Primary Key, `Autonumber`
- `LoginTime` - `Date/Time` Field
- `StaffID` - `Number` which is Foreign key to StaffTbl
- `LoginSuccess`- A `Yes/No` Field

I have a textBox, where I want to display when user last sign in.
For this I will need to filter the table on `StaffID`, for this I have stored which User is signed in value in `[TempVars]![currentUserID]`

I tried this code in Default Value Property.

```
DLast("LoginTime","LoginAuditTbl","LoginBy = " & [TempVars]![currentUserID] & " and LoginSuccess = " & "TRUE")
```

But this gives Last Record. Which is the Current Sign in.

- Any Function to get last record?
- Or, any technique to set `TextBox.Value` in VBA? on form load event?

I came across [Get 2nd last record in mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225170/get-only-second-last-record-mysql-query/), but this will give me a record, how will I assign the value to `TextBox.Value` Field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a query to get the latest date per user:

```
SELECT StaffID, Max(LoginTime) AS MaxLoginTime
FROM LoginAuditTbl
WHERE LoginSuccess = True
GROUP BY StaffID;
```

Second, use a DLookUp in your textbox to get the value from the query:

```
=DLookUp("MaxLoginTime","qryMaxLoginTimes","StaffID=" & [TempVars]![currentUserID])
```